# After import of project, Cannot instantiate class error while running the test configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, webdriver

A maven project in eclipse written in Java to automate web application testing.
The project is imported as an existing maven project in Eclipse. The same imported project is working on my co-worker's system while facing the error on another system. Tried to verify other posts and tried to fix the issue, but still no luck.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.8.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.odlproject.tests.SmokeTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:27)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:63)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:561)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1273)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1260)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: il/co/topq/difido/model/execution/Node
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at il.co.topq.difido.ReportManager.createReporterInstances(ReportManager.java:307)
    at il.co.topq.difido.ReportManager.<init>(ReportManager.java:38)
    at il.co.topq.difido.ReportManager.getInstance(ReportManager.java:46)
    at com.selenium.commons.AbstractTestClass.<init>(AbstractTestClass.java:12)
    at com.odlproject.tests.SmokeTest.<init>(SmokeTest.java:42)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: il.co.topq.difido.model.execution.Node
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 33 more
```

This is test.java file

```
package com.odlproject.tests;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.odlproject.pages.DataSet;
import com.odlproject.pages.DeviceConfiurationPage;
import com.odlproject.pages.DrugLibrariesPage;
import com.odlproject.pages.HomePage;
import com.odlproject.pages.LoginPage;
import com.odlproject.pages.MasterDrugLibrary;
import com.odlproject.pages.ProfilesPage;
import com.selenium.commons.AbstractTestClass;
import com.selenium.commons.CommonCode;
import com.selenium.commons.Configuration;
import com.selenium.commons.Screenshot;

@Listeners(Screenshot.class)
public class SmokeTest extends AbstractTestClass {

    public WebDriver driver = Configuration.browser();
    public LoginPage login;
    public HomePage home;
    public MasterDrugLibrary master;
    public DrugLibrariesPage dlp;
    public CommonCode common;
    public DeviceConfiurationPage dc;
    public ProfilesPage profile;
    public DataSet ds;

    public SmokeTest() {
        ds = new DataSet();
        login = new LoginPage();
        home = new HomePage();
        master = new MasterDrugLibrary();
        dlp = new DrugLibrariesPage();
        common = new CommonCode();
        dc = new DeviceConfiurationPage();
        profile = new ProfilesPage();

    }

    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void invokeBrowser() {

        driver.get(Configuration.LoginURL());
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void navigtoHome() {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(Configuration.LoginURL());
        login.loginToAPP(Configuration.username, Configuration.password);
        // home.validateHomePage();
        // common.waitMethod(3);

    }

    @AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void closeBrowser() { 
        driver.quit();
    }

@Test(testName = "logout", description = "logout", groups = { "sanity", "1" }, priority = 1)
    public void logout_LoginBack() {
        home.logout();
        login.loginToAPP(Configuration.username, Configuration.password);
    }
```

If there are any additional details required, please do comment, and I will add here.

Thank you.

Comment: how are your triggering the test class? did you triggered a mvn install phase before running tests ?

Comment: I would look into this `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: il.co.topq.difido.model.execution.Node`

Comment: @Manmohan_singh After import, Update maven project was executed and then Run As TestNG.

Comment: @GC13 post your project pom.xml also

Comment: Where did you put the difido-testng artifact? maybe it is in the test scope and you use it from the main source classes?